# Sup-Norm on $\ell^\infty$ as a limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

For $x=(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in\ell^\infty$ I have to show that the sup norm can be expressed as a limit in the following way:

$$\|x\|_\infty=\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{p\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$$ 
and that for $x=(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in\ell^1$ the following holds
$$\|x\|_\infty=\lim_{p\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty |x_k|^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}.$$

I dont even know where to start, so any hint or advice is appreciated!

Comment: The second one is not defined for all $x \in l_\infty$.

Comment: I am very sorry! I will fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with a very simple case: suppose that $0 \le x \le y$. What is $$\lim_{p\to \infty} \left(x^p + y^p\right)^{1/p}?$$ If you have trouble, rewrite it in terms of $y$ and $t = \frac xy$.

Once you've figured out what happens when $n = 2$, it will be much easier to see what happens for higher $n$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just to make sure that I got the right thing: In the case you described above the limit is $ \lim_{p\to\infty}\left(x^p+y^p\right)^{1/p}=y $, right?

Comment: Yes. $\lim_{p\to \infty} M^{1/p} = 1$ for fixed $M > 0$, which allows an application of the squeeze theorem to get your answer.